# GPSd library for C++

Tags: c++, gpsd

I have an application which needs to check the current location every so often (configurable but usually between 5 seconds and 5 minutes), I have previously been checking this by calling a Python script and parsing the terminal output in C++, which is obviously not he best solution.

I would like to be able to communicate with GPSd from within C++ but cannot seem to find a suitable library, is there something obvious I am missing or will I have to find another way around this?

Comment: Does the one that `GPSd` provides suffice?  "[The GPSD project provides client-side libraries in C, C++, and Python that exercise the sockets export](http://gpsd.berlios.de/client-howto.html#_the_sockets_interface)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the gpsd homepage](http://catb.org/gpsd/):

> **The gpsd distribution includes** a linkable C service library, **a C++ wrapper class**, and a Python module **that developers of gpsd-aware applications can use to encapsulate all communication with gpsd**.

So there's no separate project, the gpsd source download itself contains the library you're looking for.